# Missing 2G only on my Galaxy s4 I9505 on lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, mobile-network, 2g

I have a problem with receiving calls and text messages due to a weak 3G signal, now I want to make my phone and force it to work on the 2G mode only, but since I am on lollipop 5.0.1 I don't have this as a choice. I tried using this code: `#*#*4636#*#*` but it doesn't work with me. I also tried a few apps from the play store (e.g. [Toggle Network Type 5.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/widget-toggle-network-type-5-0-xda-t2945406) which was specifically made for Lollipop) but nothing works.

My phone is rooted.

Comment: On my 5.1.1 device I have it in *Settings › Network › Mobile networks › Preferred network type*, on my 4.4 device as well. There I can select between "LTE/3G/2G". I'd wonder why 5.0 shouldn't have that setting. Guess it's rather some Sammy-specific issue.

Comment: This widget has nothing to do with my problem, I tried it yesterday. Even though thanks a lot for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Samsung devices require root access to launch the hidden testing menu. The normal code will not work in the dialer; even with ADB, you don't have access to the menu.

Since you have root access, just type the following in a terminal on your phone and the hidden testing menu should appear:

```
su -c "am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings"
```

It may be easier through my app [Root Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials) that can do this and more. You can find that test menu under "Device Info".

Comment: That exactly what I needed, the application does the job, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The right code is `*#*#4636#*#*`. If this doesn't work then try to use an app from play store. It is called [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo&hl=en). Another possible solution to your problem is described in this [link](http://www.clearevo.com/blog/howto/2012/10/10/android_force_wcdma_or_gsm_or_auto_from_shell.html][1]), but it depends on the file structure of your OS.

Comment: @Mohdows did you pay attention to the order the asterisks and hashes appear? If so (and your input started with an `*` and not a `#`), what happens when you dial this code?

Comment: @Izzy yes I did pay attention to the order; and I did even try other combinations to make sure that I am using the correct code, and for you information nothing happened when I dial the code.

Comment: @Mohdows OK – this time your details where clear as glass :)

Comment: @andreas I've tried the application you mentioned above, but it doesn't give me anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the App called Radio Switcher. This works on my Blackberry Keyone